# Static HTML page navigation into an ASP.NET.MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm sure there's a simple answer but I can't think of it.

I'm working with a designer who is using Dreamweaver to produce a series of static HTML pages and style sheets. These pages navigate to each other using standard  anchors.

However, on a couple of pages there needs to be a navigation to a page under ASP.NET.MVC 2 (from here I do all the coding stuff to the backend) which has Form input etc.

What is the best way to ...

1: Navigate from a standard HTML page into ASP.NET.MVC  2(Home controller)

And/Or

2: The best way to have ASP.NET.MVC output the static HTML pages. Meaning the ASP.NET.MVC  controller reads the static HTML (from a cache) then outputs it to the View

Hope this makes sense, thanks in advance.
Any links will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to the root of an MVC-based site, if would just be the URL as the index view of the home controller is usually the default.  Something like http://www.website.com.  However, if you want a specific controller/view then the the syntax would be http://www.website.com/{controller}/{view}.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Andy. Obvious, to say the least.
I’ve done all the hard bits EF4, POCO, T4, Repository, Unity DI, but couldn’t figure this simple one out.
But then again I’m not really a web developer (WPF is my thing)